# Playing a audio in each cell of HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a newbie and would like some help here please , trying to make a button play when clicked in each table cell of html table. This is my fiddle link which I'm working on, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hello and Welcome on SO! Your Link is missing ;-)

Comment: @  MiBrock Sorry this my link...https://jsfiddle.net/dani_94/d2hg0Lg6/

Comment: So where is your Problem? Any Errors? Please add some mor information to your Question.

Comment: @MiBrock Problem solved with the help of Brunis's anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way your events are set up, you just add the event to the element in Javascript instead like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('play');
btn.onclick = play;
```

I edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2hg0Lg6/1/

I edited the fiddle with multiple buttons and a loop to attach the event to all, i'll leave it as an exercise to you to play different sounds with different buttons :)

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.onclick = play;
});
```

The updated fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/d2hg0Lg6/2/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Exactly what I'm looking for. @Brunis

Comment: You add a button to each cell, add a class to all of them, attach the click event to all elements with that class and then probe the event for which target triggered it and act accordingly :)

Comment: Yes its helpful. One more clarification please, If I want to implement it every cell with different voice ,How can i achieve that?

Comment: You could just save the url in a data-attr* for each button, then pass that to the <audio> element (there by reusing it instead of having multiple and play. But i'll leave that exercise to you :)

Comment: Hey Thank you but I'm totally confused and messed up as I'm completely new to html& javascript . Will keep trying as you said. :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated fiddle, will work on it. Thats so HELPFUL . :)

Comment: Hey Brunis, sorry but couldn't succeed, do I have to use something like input tag to do so.

Comment: Methods called by an event pass an event object, from that event object you can get the clicked element. So if you add the specific url to each button in eg. data attributes, you can extract it in the event and set the src on the audio object and then play it :)

Comment: Hi Brunis, attached the link, can you please look at it tell me if I'm doing the right way as you said, thank you.  https://jsfiddle.net/dani_94/d2hg0Lg6/7/

Comment: @Amy_ella yes, you are doing it right, i added a few steps https://jsfiddle.net/d2hg0Lg6/10/ now you just need to set the src of the audio element :)

Comment: help me, you mean like this sourceMp3.src='http://ww.guidetojapanese.org/audio/a.mp3'; or audio.src='audio/mp3/'; If you don't mind can please help me finish this off  as I have to proceed to next level as soon as possible thank you